# Problem Installing EGIT

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, egit

I have the following configuration

- OS: Win XP
- Eclipse: Galileo

And i want to install EGIT on it (i already have subclipse). I tried going to `Help -> Install New Software` but EGIT was not on the list. I tried downloaing from the site but download link http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates is not opening in the browser (chrome)

Please help me how to install Egit.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the update site (see below) *really* don't work, you still can try the [zip download option](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4674476/where-can-i-find-an-updatesite-zip-for-egit-on-eclipse-3-6-behind-a-firewall).

---

But you should be able to declare and use the Egit update site, as illustrated in the [Egit tutorial](http://www.vogella.de/articles/EGit/article.html#eclipseinstallation), provided you have the right [Network connection preferences](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/reference/ref-net-preferences.htm), allowing you Internet access.

[image: Egit installation]

> Use the [Eclipse Update manager](http://www.vogella.de/articles/Eclipse/article.html#updatemanager) to install the EGit plugin from http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates

Comment: when i click on `Help -> Install new Software` i didn't get the option to add instead i get the option to choose from available plugins like this http://www.imageupload.org/getfile.php?id=38128&a=c961026607e72304c0c0606d032547a5&t=4dc8d434&o=5F08CB2D852273141434BD9995B895B35E14982BCD203B0B155BFBD9DEA4F0994214D22D85&n=eclipse.JPG&i=1

Comment: @jimy: you need first to add the update site, by clicking on the 'Available Software Sites' link

Comment: @jimy: no need to click on "Add" on the "Available Software" dialog. Once you have added the update site in the "Available Software Sites" dialog, you will be able to select that same site from the dialog shown in the screenshot above, *without* clicking on "Add".

Comment: @jimy: note, one you have updated the "Available Software Sites", **close** the "Available Software" dialog and then reopen it (through Help/Install New software) in order to see the update site you just added in the "Available Software Sites" dialog.

Answer (score 2):

I had a very similar problem to this.

I hadn't realised, but the problem was that I still had a proxy server configured (which was no longer turned on).

To solve, I went to Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections.

Would have nice for Eclipse to actually tell me there was a problem to do with the proxy server rather than throwing/reporting some obscure exception...

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the egit link to Eclipse, so it searches it.  In the text box it presents (when you go to Install New Software on the Help menu) enter the egit URL and hit enter - it should find the egit plugin and allow it to be selected for install.

Comment: i did that but the list goes away :(

Comment: Oh that's not good... what about trying the Eclipse Marketplace.  Go Help > Eclipse Marketplace. Locate egit there and kick off the install.

Comment: i didnt have Marketplace option :(